# ActionScript 3.0 - Variable sharing, across two movieclips. COMPLEX

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, action

I have a really interesting problem, associated with the animation of my main character in the development of my mobile game.

I have one movieclip, of my players arm/attackArm, attached to a moving animation of his body [on frame 1 of HERO]

I also have another movieclip of an arm/attackArm, attached to his jumping and falling movieclips [on frame 2 + 3 of HERO]

I need cross-communication between the two, through a variable or variables of THROWframe / CurrentThrowFrame. To be able to fix a certain bug.

The bug is that, when i throw the spear, and jump (mid throw animation) he continues where he left off in the throwing animation. HOWEVER,,,

When I jump, then throw [regardless of if hes on Frame 2 or 3, falling or proceeding upward, because both share the same ARM] ;;; upon hitting the ground, his throw animation resets back to frame 0, regardless if he was in mid throw whilst in the air.

Can anyone help? This is very specific, I Know.
Any and all Help welcome.

### Here is a smidgen of code.

```
    // PLAYER : SHOOT (OVERALL)
    public function playerShoot(m:MouseEvent):void
    {

        //Running Shoot
        ///////////////
        if (JungleBob.player.currentFrame == 1 && JungleBob.player.runBody.runBody2.playerWeaponArm.currentFrame == 1)

        {
        var angle_in_radF1:Number = Math.atan2(mouseY - (JungleBob.player.y + JungleBob.player.runBody.runBody2.playerWeaponArm.y - (36)), mouseX - (JungleBob.player.x + JungleBob.player.runBody.runBody2.playerWeaponArm.x + (32)));
        var heroBullet_mcF1:MovieClip = new projectile_spear();
        Heros_Bullets_Array.push(heroBullet_mcF1);


        heroBullet_mcF1.x = (JungleBob.player.x + (JungleBob.player.runBody.runBody2.playerWeaponArm.x) + (32));
        heroBullet_mcF1.y = (JungleBob.player.y + (JungleBob.player.runBody.runBody2.playerWeaponArm.y) - (36));

        heroBullet_mcF1.rotation = angle_in_radF1 * 180/Math.PI;
        JungleBob.player.runBody.runBody2.playerWeaponArm.rotation = angle_in_radF1 * 180/Math.PI + (10);

        addChild(heroBullet_mcF1);
        JungleBob.mainClass.randomThrowSoundTraffic();

        JungleBob.player.runBody.runBody2.playerWeaponArm.gotoAndPlay(2);

        (new Tween(JungleBob.Vcamera,'x',Strong.easeOut,630,625,0.5,true));

        }

        //Jumping and Falling Shoot
        ///////////////////////////
        if (JungleBob.player.currentFrame >= 2 && JungleBob.player.playerWeaponArm.currentFrame == 1)

        {
        var angle_in_rad:Number = Math.atan2(mouseY - (JungleBob.player.y + JungleBob.player.playerWeaponArm.y - (36)), mouseX - (JungleBob.player.x + JungleBob.player.playerWeaponArm.x + (32)));
        var heroBullet_mc:MovieClip = new projectile_spear();
        Heros_Bullets_Array.push(heroBullet_mc);

        heroBullet_mc.x = (JungleBob.player.x + (JungleBob.player.playerWeaponArm.x) + (32));
        heroBullet_mc.y = (JungleBob.player.y + (JungleBob.player.playerWeaponArm.y) - (36));

        heroBullet_mc.rotation = angle_in_rad * 180/Math.PI;
        JungleBob.player.playerWeaponArm.rotation = angle_in_rad * 180/Math.PI + (10);
        addChild(heroBullet_mc);
        JungleBob.mainClass.randomThrowSoundTraffic();


        JungleBob.player.playerWeaponArm.gotoAndPlay(2);

        (new Tween(JungleBob.Vcamera,'x',Strong.easeOut,630,625,0.5,true));


        }

    }


            // PLAYER : SHOOT (LISTENERS)
            //


            //Other Throw Frame Listener
            public function otherListener(e:Event):void 
            {
                if ((hero_mc.canJump == true) &&  ThrowFrame == 0)
                {
                    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, throwFrameListener);
                }
            }

            //Throw Frame Listener
            public function throwFrameListener (e:Event):void
            {
                if (JungleBob.player.currentFrame == 1)
                {
                    ThrowFrame = JungleBob.player.runBody.runBody2.playerWeaponArm.currentFrame;
                }

                if ( (JungleBob.player.currentFrame >= 2) && (ThrowFrame >= 2) && (hero_mc.yVelocity <= 0) )
                {
                    JungleBob.player.playerWeaponArm.gotoAndPlay(ThrowFrame);
                    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, throwFrameListener);
                }

            }
```

---

BEST OF LUCK 
&&
THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: Put some code comments to explain what your trying to accomplish in your posted code.  It's not entirely clear (at least to me) what the problem even is.   you can communicate up the display tree using the `parent` keyword.

Comment: can you post an image of your character setup (movieclip timeline), as on a keyframe, in code, I think all the objects are recreated, which is what sounds like what's happening with your arm.

Comment: somewhat related, and possible for the future, but you could also check out DragonBones: http://dragonbones.effecthub.com/ or Spine http://esotericsoftware.com/ for easy skeleton animation